# How to manage multiple kubernetes namespaces in a terraform project

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I've been using terraform for a while now and I have deployed everything into separate clusters. Now due to cost, we'd like to merge the different clusters into one cluster and use kubernetes namespaces.

My desired outcome would be that I could call `terraform apply - var="kubernetes_namespace=my-namespace"` and it would create the namespace which could live alongside my other namespaces, however, due to how terraform remote state is managed, any new deployment will overwrite the old and I can't have co-existing namespaces.

When I try to redeploy another namespace I get
`namespace        = "deploy-pr-image" -> "test-second-branch-pr" # forces replacement`

I can see why because it's writing everything to a single workspace file.

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket               = "my-tf-state"
    key                  = "terraform-services.tfstate"
    region               = "us-west-1"
    workspace_key_prefix = "workspaces"
    #dynamodb_table       = "terraform-state-lock-dynamo"
  }
}
```

Is there some way to use the workspace/namespace combination to keep terraform from overwriting my other namespace ?

Comment: You would need to switch the workspace first and probably keep a different set of variables for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

Since now you'll be merging all your clusters into a single one, it would make sense to only have a backend where you can manage the state of the cluster rather than having multiple backends per Kubernetes namespaces.

I suggest you to update your module or root deployment to be flexible enough that it can create X number of Kubernetes namespaces resources rather than a single one using `count` or `for_each`.